# Delphi Firemonkey creating TExpanders and TLabels at runtime

Tags: delphi, components, firemonkey

Using Rad Studio 10.3

I am creating TExpanders at runtime based on a FireDAC query. However i am running into an issue setting the Parent of the label to the expander i have just created.

I am using the following to create the components

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  // Populate previous saved conversions stringgrid
  FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  FDQuery1.Close;
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT convert from conversions');
  FDQuery1.Open;
  i := 1;
  while not FDQuery1.Eof do
  begin
    // Create Expanders here to display database query to user
    exp := TExpander.Create(Self);
    exp.Parent := layoutDBDisplay;
    exp.Align := TAlignLayout.Top;
    exp.Name := 'dbExp' + i.ToString;  
    exp.Height := 100;
    exp.TextSettings.Font.Size := 14;
    exp.TextSettings.Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];

    // Create TLabel inside of above expander
    lab := TLabel.Create(Self);
    lab.Parent := TExpander;
    lab.Align := TAlignLayout.Top;
    lab.Name := 'dbResLabel' + i.ToString;
    inc(i);
    FDQuery1.Next;
  end;
  FDQuery1.Close;

end;
```

The issue is lies in this line

```
lab.Parent := expName;
```

Obviously the above won't compile because of the following

```
[dcc32 Error] frmConverter.pas(266): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TFmxObject' and 'class of TExpander'
```

Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```
lab.Parent := TExpander;
```

should be

```
lab.Parent := Exp;
```

Comment: Oh! Was actually simple. Thanks a bunch